# JS. Cклеивание объектов

Tags: javascript

Нужно переписать функцию так чтобы она выполнялась для неопределенного количества объектов.

```
function assignObjects(obj1,obj2){
    var conv = Object.assign({},obj1,obj2)
    return conv

}
console.log(assignObjects({ x: 10, y: 20 },{ z: 30 }))
console.log(assignObjects({ x: 10 }, { x: 20, y: 30 }))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function assignObjects(...objects){
    return Object.assign({}, ...objects);;    
}

console.log(assignObjects([{ x: 10, y: 20 },{ z: 30 }]));
console.log(assignObjects([{ x: 10 }, { x: 20, y: 30 }]));
```